# 'Message Send Failure' to one contact from iPhone - have tried everything

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, text, sms

I'm trying to send messages to my father's phone number (iPhone) but the 'Not Delivered' error is always being thrown back. Currently, iMessage is disabled but I've tried it enabled but, as suspected, it has no effect for **text messages** (when I don't have WiFi access).

I've tried everything. Got a new SIM, I'm not on his blocked number list (or vice versa), have tried resetting network settings, and have tried deleting contact.

Have run out of ideas and am pulling my hair out over this. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do messages get through if they are sent from your father's phone to yours? If yes, can you reply, do you get a green or blue bubble if you do so?

Comment: Also, can you message other contacts successfully?

Comment: @nohillside, messages do go through from my father’s phone to mine, yes. They do take a long time to send as SMS messages though bearing in mind I currently have iMessage off. Replying returns the same error and I can’t reply in a thread because iMessage is off.

Comment: @Allan, yes. I’m having no issues like this with anyone else.

Comment: Out of curiosity...could your father have inadvertently "tagged" your message as "junk?"  See [Block, filter, and report messages on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/block-filter-and-report-messages-iph203ab0be4/ios).

Comment: @Allan, I just read through the Apple support page you linked. From what I understand, reporting a message once as junk will not result in messages not being able to be sent unless blocked, which isn’t the case. “Filter unknown senders” is also off as that is something I checked.

Comment: On your device, disable all but Wi-Fi.  Then try Facetime and messaging him.  Also try FT/msg with someone else who has an iPhone.  What are the results?

Comment: @Allan, tried that as instructed. FT works with my father but messaging doesn’t. FT works with my brother and so does messaging. Both my brother and father have iMessage on but I don’t currently as I say.

Comment: That means it’s definitely not a carrier issue.  Try deleting your contact on your fathers phone and then messaging him

Comment: @Allan, no joy with that, unfortunately. Already tried the other way round with deleting my father as a contact from my phone and that didn’t work either.

Comment: Turn on cellular then send your dad an SMS via his phone number.  See if that works.

Comment: @Allan, just tried sending text with mobile data on and WiFi off. No joy. Same issue.

Comment: At a loss at the moment.  I'll have to deep dive into settings.  I have two phones here, but I can’t replicate the problem

Comment: @Allan, thank you. Yep, I've no idea how the issue can be replicated as I'm really not sure what is causing the issue in the first place.